# Java date is showing in the wrong format when set to JQuery Datepicker

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, date, datepicker

I've been looking some time on this but can't figure it out and it's frustrating me :)

I have a JQuery datepicker on my form, which is rendered in JSF with Spring WEBMVC as background. When I select a date on the datepicker, it shows as yyyy-MM-dd (f.e. 2014-12-10) because it is set up this way:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
               $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()
       });
   </script>
```

However, the default date returned from my Java.util.Date class sets the value for the DatePicker to:

```
Wed Dec 10 00:00:00 EET 2014
```

I find this annoying and I would like to have the default date, set on the datepicker by Java, also to be displayed as yy-mm-dd. How can I force that?

JSP:

```
        <th>Update Expected</th>
        <td>
            <form:input path="updateExpected" id="datepicker" />
            <br />
            <form:errors path="updateExpected" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
        </td>
```

My Java underlying is simple:

```
private Date updateExpected;

public Date getUpdateExpected() {
    return updateExpected;
}
```

Thanks!
Joachim

Answer (score 0):

I would pass this date as a string and request attribute and use `$("#datepicker").datepicker( "setDate", $mydatestringfromjava );`

```
private Date updateExpected;

public String getUpdateExpected() {
  SimpleDateformat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
  return sdf.format(<your-date>);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the data binding between JSP and Spring seems to look for the method getUpdateExpected() which returns a Date. I managed to 'fix' it now by including two fields in my java class: updateExpected and updatedExpectedString in which I return the String in the right format. Every time I set the value of the String I also update the Date value. Very ugly :( but seems to work for now.

Comment: I am positive that it should work. Can you post your full code?